# The leaves of my aloe plant are growing stacked. Is that okay?

Tags: aloe

So I have had this aloe plant for three years and she has been doing fairly well, producing plenty of pups (the ones in the pot have grown since I separated 7 from her 4 months ago) but I have noticed that her leaves are growing on top of each other instead of fanning out. Should I be worried or is there something that I can do to help her? 
Thanks in advance! [image]

Comment: Does the pot have drainage holes? How close to a window is your plant - trying to establish how much light it gets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's growing perfectly.  Believe it or not Aloe vera exist no where naturally in the world.  It is thought that is comes form North Africa.   Today, we have many plant that we call Aloe vera that are not true Aloe vera.  Some growing in spiral and some grow stacked.  Many aloes grow stacked.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This is my first plant and I want to do right by her.

Answer (score 0):

The light question by Bamboo above is an important one. If this is in fact Aloe vera, it looks starved for light. Unless it is in front of a south-facing window it's probably not getting enough light for the typical compact growth habit.

Has this plant been fertilized? excessive fertilizer will also cause abnormal growth. Looking at the plant, it appears it may have been fertilized relatively recently. Note short leaves lower on the plant, longer leaves near the top.

So, to address your specific question; your plant is not exhibiting typical Aloe vera growth. To improve the compactness of the plant it needs more light. If you are fertilizing you should cut back until you are able to provide better light.

Comment: I have not fertilized the plant since I have had it. To address the short leaves at the bottom, they are from where I have cut some off. I can try it by a more south facing window, however the only option is facing west and I have a younger aloe plant growing there, otherwise north facing is my only option in my unit.

Comment: As long as you're OK with it, do what you can. It isn't normal growth, but I've seen much, much worse. You've done well by removing the offsets and should continue that . They can get very pot-bound left to their own devices.

Comment: I have moved it to where it will hopefully get more light. Thank you for your help!